# Back to app button, starts over my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

When my application redirects the user to safari (happens also with other redirections not only safari) using

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL ..)
```

and then the user presses the "Back to app" button, the app starts over instead of continue from the point before the redirection.

I have a settings table and redirection happens when you press a cell. (imagine a cell with "more apps from us")

I know that this is not the default behavior, so I miss something which I cannot find through google. Anyone who can point me to an article or had an idea? Thanks in advance.

*Screenshot of the "back to app" button*

[image]

**Edit:** If that plays a role, I am not using a Storyboard. So taking in mind comments maybe I did not set correctly the navigation controller so there is not an hierarchy stack?

Based on @MaximSysenko observation, the app stops / crashes when the redirection happens

This is where the redirection happens:

```
override public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.section {

...

        //appSpecific
    case 1:
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {

        } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "permissions"), object: nil)
            //tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        }

...

    case 3:
        else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            let url = URL(string:          "itms://itunes.apple.com/us/developer/some-id")
            UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        }
```

Comment: When you mean "Back to app" do you mean the thin status bar back button?

Comment: I mean the upper left corner back to app button which is not programmable. I think introduced in iOS 9. Let me upload a screenshot

Comment: @GeorgeVardikos Please share screenshot, Which button are you talking about.

Comment: I updated the question with the screenshot

Comment: This sounds something more to do with your logic when responding to the app becoming "active". Do you have any observers that monitor the `UIApplicationState`? If not that then maybe something when the view appears?

Comment: No i do not have implement any observers yet. I will do a search for what you suggest thanks

Comment: @GeorgeVardikos It's not that I'm suggesting them. I'm just saying if you have any - they might be interfering with your application's logic. Does your AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunching` get called when you return to your app?

Comment: @Chackle No it is not called the `didFinishLaunching `. Also I am not using a storyboard does this matter?

Comment: @GeorgeVardikos Seems like your app is crashing for some reason after redirecting to Safari. Check memory usage.

Comment: @MaximSysenko indeed it crashes! without an error message though in the console. Just stops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your Info.plist contains a true value for this key:

```
<key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>
```

This will result in your app completely exiting when it goes to the background. Set this key value to false in order to have your app live through the transition from foreground to background back to foreground.